# What is the best way to write heredocs in php and how to keep function max 20 lines

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Following is the code of Class Admin that contains two method

```
listRecord();
Details($id);
```

The code is working fine but i don't like this code because function is huge and coupled and i don't want to use heredocs in function Kindly guide me what is the best way to write heredocs and how to separate heredocs in separate function.

Admin Class

```
Class Admin{

   public function listRecord() {

    $query = "select Report_type, Report_Id, Report_Reults,Patient_name, Patient_Address, "
            . "Patient_Phone from Patient join Reports "
            . "on Patient.Patient_ID = Reports.Patient_ID ";

    $result = $this->conn->query($query);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row

        echo <<<HTML

        <h2>Report's Data</h2>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Patient Name</th>
        <th>Patient Address</th>
        <th>Patient Phone</th>
        <th>Report Type</th>
        <th>Report Results</th>
    </tr>
<tr>
HTML;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo"       
<tr>
<td>  $row[Patient_name]    </td>
<td>  $row[Patient_Address] </td>
<td>  $row[Patient_Phone]   </td>
<td>  $row[Report_type]     </td>
<td>  $row[Report_Reults]   </td>

<td><a href='../Admin/AdminData.php?del_id=$row[Report_Id]'>Delete</a></td>
<td><a href='../Admin/AdminData.php?report_id=$row[Report_Id]'>Details</a></td>

</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
}

}


  public function Details($id) {

    $this->data_id = $id;

    $query = "select Report_type, Report_Id, Report_Reults,Patient_name, Patient_Address, "
            . "Patient_Phone from Patient join Reports WHERE "
            . "Reports.Report_Id=$this->data_id and Patient.Patient_ID=$this->data_id ";

    $result = $this->conn->query($query);



    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row

        echo <<<HTML

        <h2>$row[Patient_name] Data</h2>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Patient Name</th>
        <th>Patient Address</th>
        <th>Patient Phone</th>
        <th>Report Type</th>
        <th>Report Results</th>
    </tr>
<tr>
HTML;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            echo"       
<tr>
<td>  $row[Patient_name]    </td>
<td>  $row[Patient_Address] </td>
<td>  $row[Patient_Phone]   </td>
<td>  $row[Report_type]     </td>
<td>  $row[Report_Reults]   </td>

</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with phpMyAdmin, which is a graphical tool for administrators to manage a MySQL or MariaDB database installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try saving the HTML for both functions in different files and including them when required. You could use .phtml format for these files, which is HTML with some PHP.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    require_once FILE_PATH; // Path to the specific file needed in the function.
}
```